# Event not associated on control error while using updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, updatepanel

I am using an update panel inside which I have a treeview control. I wrote an async trigger with the same. I am getting an error which I couldn't solve as I am seeing it for the first time. I also got this error for the my control which was in update panel but that got solved as i used `$` for separation of parent and child. Now i am having  problem for finding event name. Following is my error

```
Could not find an event named 'PopulateNode' on associated control 'TreeView_Parent_Child' for the trigger in UpdatePanel '_updatepnlTreeview'.
```

My code is

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Visible="true" runat="server"
                                        ScrollBars="Auto">
                                        <div style="overflow: auto; height: 400px; width:230px; border-right: solid; border-right-color: gray">
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="_updatepnlTreeview" UpdateMode="Conditional"  runat="server">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView_Parent_Child" EnableClientScript="true" align="left"
                                                AutoGenerateDataBindings="true" LeafNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" NodeStyle-ForeColor="Black"
                                                PopulateNodesFromClient="true" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode" 

                                                HoverNodeStyle-BackColor="ActiveBorder" Font-Size="Small" ImageSet="Arrows" NodeStyle-HorizontalPadding="5px">
                                                <HoverNodeStyle Font-Bold="true" BackColor="Beige" />
                                                <Nodes>
                                                </Nodes>
                                                <NodeStyle ForeColor="Black" />
                                                <LeafNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" />

                                            </asp:TreeView>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView_Parent_Child" EventName="PopulateNode" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EventName needs to be changed to the name of the event instead of the method:

```
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView_Parent_Child" EventName="TreeNodePopulate" />
    </Triggers>
```

Comment: This works but I have 1 more reqirment, on my treenode click, I am redirecting from my masterpage(which has my treeview) to a different page where I show the data that lies in the selected node. My problem is that the other nodes are also expanding with the node which was clicked.